# Teenagers who can use a device to turn into monsters?

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I watched this cartoon around 2010. It was about some teenagers who can use a device to turn into monsters. There were, I think, four teams which fought over some magical stones. The hero team consisted of two boys and a girl. I remember that the girl was the daughter of the main villain and had some markings on her face (like her father).

There was some tournament that took place. The main character's main monster was something like "The Platinum Giant" or something like that. The other teams (or the evil teams) were all under the command of the main villain. They competed with each other so they can earn new monsters (but I am not very sure if they earned monsters).

There where these old guys (I think they were senseis), which the teacher of the main characters was one of. The main villain was also one of them, but he got kicked out and started the evil teams. The main character used his father's monsters. His father disappeared and left him his monsters.

It is not "Monster Rancher" or "Chaotic".

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You've provided some helpful information in your question, but the more info you provide, the more likely you are to get the answer you're looking for. Can you tell us more about the other teams? How does the main villain come into play? Check out [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for tips on asking a story ID question, and edit any more details you can recall into your question.

Comment: Did the main bad guy look like [this](http://monster-rancher.wikia.com/wiki/Holly%27s_Father)? It's not a great match, but e.g. "The main villain was also one of them, but he got kicked out" fits Holly's father in the *Monster Rancher* anime / games.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not Monster Rancher. I have also edited my post to include popular answers that i ha seen.

Comment: It was a complete shot in the dark. My only other suggestion would be to choose all the genre elements / tropes you can think of from the lists here: *[Search for titles by genre - Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/search/genre)* ...

Comment: Obligatory mention that marking a question as a Duplicate is not a censure. It's largely a bookkeeping method, to ensure that the details spread over multiple questions all point to the same place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be **[Redakai: Conquer the Kairu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redakai:_Conquer_the_Kairu_(TV_series))**?

[image: Redaki splash page showing the three main character]

Had various teams of villains up against the kids/heroes, who were trained by sensei.
The leader of the good team was looking to find his father.

The character Maya had markings on her face, and turns out to be related to the main villain.

Comment: It is Redakai: Conquer the Kairu. Thanks so much Brian.

Comment: @Bavnqta: Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

**Star Driver: Kagayaki no Takuto**.
This has some elements that you have mentioned. The characters use giants they call "Cybodies" and wants to possess  all of them. The protagonist uses a White one.

The only other anime I found which released in 2010 with characters controlling monsters was **Bakugan Battle Brawlers**. **New Vestroia** and **Gundalian Invaders** both released in 2010.

Comment: It is sadly non of them. But thank you for answering.